# d3.js insert line path by "datum" or line (data)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I was trying to plot a time-pressure line chart.

The data is an array of objects, named "res"

```
[
  {Time: , 
   Psi: 
  }, 
  ...
]
```

I defined the x, y axis, and line function like these

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(res, d => d.Time)).range([0, width]),
    y  = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(res, d=>d.psi)]).range([height, 0]),

var line = d3.line()
             .x(function(d) { return x(d.Time) })
             .y(function(d) { return y(d.psi) });
```

Every thing was very standard set-up.
When I insert line element to the chart, I found two ways to insert them.

**Method 1, with "datum"**

```
svg.append("path")
   .datum(res) //"datum"
   .attr("class", "line") 
   .attr("d", line);
```

**Method 2, with by line(res)**

```
svg.insert("path")
   .attr("class", "line") 
   .attr("d", line(res)); //line(res), like a function
```

Both methods work, just wondering are there any difference between these two methods?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two methods is that by method one, you have assigned `res` as the "datum" object of the node. That means that if you were to store it in a variable - or I think even if you would re-select them (not sure though) - you should be able to reliably access the current value using `.attr('...', function(d) { });`. That can be useful if you want to do stuff to it, like animations or styling, and the value might update often - so it's a hassle to carry it around.

Other than that, there is no real difference. One of the things I like to use `.datum()` for is when I have a container for every shape and I want to add a node to every container, then it might be useful to use `container.select('text').datum((d) => d)` to feed the datum object from the container to its text child.